# mat-tab-label disable keyboard interaction

Tags: html, angular, tabs, angular-material

I have a material tab component (**mat-tab-gruop**), and i needed a search bar inside the **mat-tab-header**, so i added a disabled tab containing only a mat-tab-label, and placed it inside it my search bar component.

Like this:

```
<mat-tab-group>  
  <mat-tab disabled>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <search-bar></search-bar>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

My problem is when I press an arrow key, instead of moving the cursor between characters, the focus changes to the other headers.

That happened because angular-meterial use Keyboard interaction to move focus between tabs.

I want to disable this Keyboard interactions behaviour, and keep focus on my search bar. I know I can move back focus after losing it to another tab header, then back to the search tab-header, using binding to (selectedTabChanged) and move focus back. I want the focus to always stay on the search bar input, so I’ll be able use arrows to move between charcters.

[stackbiltz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xufnk7?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-animations-example.ts)

**my code:**

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="'1'">

  <mat-tab disabled>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput class="search" [value]="searchText">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="tab1">
    <p>some content</p>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="tab2">
    <p>some content</p>
  </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: this was fixed in 16.1
https://github.com/angular/components/pull/27091

Answer (score -1):

Stop the key events propagating from the input field to stop them reaching the tab widget

```
<mat-form-field>
          <input matInput class="search" [value]="searchText" (keydown)="suppressKeyEvent($event)">
        </mat-form-field>
```

and

```
export class TabGroupAnimationsExample {
  suppressKeyEvent (event:any) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xufnk7-keqvdt

Just picking up angular and had to do something similar to above, so if anyone knows of a more 'angurly' way to do it (i.e. can you write the key suppression as some kind of imported module/directive?) that'd be kewl.